# MYSQL INT addition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to bring the INT values from mysql and do a addition and finally update the database. But this doesn't seem to do update? How can I fix this?

```
$resultSecond = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Furniture");
while($lineSecond = mysql_fetch_array($resultSecond)) {
    $item     = $lineSecond["Item"]; 
    $janD     = $lineSecond["January"];
    $febD     = $lineSecond["February"];
    $marD     = $lineSecond["March"];
    $pastVals = $lineSecond["yearSale"];
    $totalCT  = $lineSecond["monthSale"];

    $totThisM = ($janD + $febD + $marD + $pastVals + $totalCT);
    mysql_query("UPDATE Furniture SET Furniture = '".$totThisM."' WHERE Item ='$item' LIMIT 1");
}
```

Comment: use mysql_error() and see whats going on for the update command.

Comment: We don't know, because you don't show either the database schema or the error message you get. But we *do* know that this is a bad way to update; you can update all your database with a single `UPDATE` query, as in `UPDATE Furniture SET Furniture = January + February + ...`.

Comment: Why there is a "LIMIT" in your update statement ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use MySQL?

```
UPDATE `Furniture`
SET `Furniture` = (`January`+`February`+`March`+`yearSale`+`monthSale`)
```

#### Test data

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| number1 | number2 | total |
+---------+---------+-------+
|       1 |       5 |     0 |
|       2 |       3 |     0 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

And I run my query;

```
UPDATE table SET total = (`number1`+`number2`);
```

And the table is updated;

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| number1 | number2 | total |
+---------+---------+-------+
|       1 |       5 |     6 |
|       2 |       3 |     5 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

### Notes

- Removed `WHERE` clause after comment from CodeBird.
- Adjusted query after comments from Ravinder

Comment: yep, you don't even need the WHERE Item=$item neither the while loop

Comment: You also don't need `item` field value for summing up.

Comment: It should be just `SET Furniture = ( January + February + March + yearSale + monthSale )`

Comment: Thanks h | CodeBird | Ravinder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Furniture SET Furniture = '". $totThisM ."' WHERE Item ='". $item ."' LIMIT 1");
```

**Edit**

Not the right answer, see comments for details.

Comment: won't change anything

Comment: I think the variable is not converted into its value. In PHP you can pass variable into double quotes (like `$return = "The value is $var";`) but not `$return = 'The value is $var'; // Error`).

Comment: it is in double quotes, the whole query is in double quotes. That's not his issue. He has " then ' so the var will work normally there.